# error while starting flume

Tags: java, flume, flume-ng, dynatrace

I am trying to use dynatrace as a source for flume and hadoop as sink,where dynatrace and flume is on same server and hadoop is on another server.

However,when starting flume,I am getting below error :

---

> ERROR [conf-file-poller-0]
>   (org.apache.flume.conf.file.AbstractFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run:211)
>   - Unhandled error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.debug(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:120)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.register(MetricsSystemImpl.java:220)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.MetricsSystem.register(MetricsSystem.java:54)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.create(UserGroupInformation.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.(UserGroupInformation.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSEventSink.authenticate(HDFSEventSink.java:529)
>     at
>   org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSEventSink.configure(HDFSEventSink.java:247)
>     at
>   org.apache.flume.conf.Configurables.configure(Configurables.java:41)
>     at
>   org.apache.flume.conf.properties.PropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.loadSinks(PropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:373)
>     at
>   org.apache.flume.conf.properties.PropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.load(PropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:223)
>     at
>   org.apache.flume.conf.file.AbstractFileConfigurationProvider.doLoad(AbstractFileConfigurationProvider.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.flume.conf.file.AbstractFileConfigurationProvider.access$300(AbstractFileConfigurationProvider.java:38)
>     at
>   org.apache.flume.conf.file.AbstractFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(AbstractFileConfigurationProvider.java:202)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

---

This is my flume configuration file :

```
# Name the components on this agent
QKDSK305.sources = HTTPSource
QKDSK305.sinks = PurePathSink UserActionSink VisitSink NullSink
QKDSK305.channels = PurePathChannel UserActionChannel VisitChannel NullChannel

# Describe/configure HTTPSource
QKDSK305.sources.HTTPSource.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
QKDSK305.sources.HTTPSource.port = 4321
QKDSK305.sources.HTTPSource.handler = com.dynatrace.diagnostics.btexport.flume.BtExportHandler

# Describe sinks
QKDSK305.sinks.PurePathSink.type = hdfs
QKDSK305.sinks.PurePathSink.hdfs.path = hdfs://QKDSK303:9000/user/bts/pp
QKDSK305.sinks.PurePathSink.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
QKDSK305.sinks.PurePathSink.hdfs.filePrefix = export
QKDSK305.sinks.PurePathSink.hdfs.fileSuffix = .txt
QKDSK305.sinks.PurePathSink.hdfs.rollInterval = 120
QKDSK305.sinks.PurePathSink.hdfs.rollSize = 131072
QKDSK305.sinks.PurePathSink.serializer = com.dynatrace.diagnostics.btexport.flume.BtPurePathSerializerBuilder

QKDSK305.sinks.UserActionSink.type = hdfs
QKDSK305.sinks.UserActionSink.hdfs.path = hdfs://QKDSK303:9000/user/bts/pa
QKDSK305.sinks.UserActionSink.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
QKDSK305.sinks.UserActionSink.hdfs.filePrefix = export
QKDSK305.sinks.UserActionSink.hdfs.fileSuffix = .txt
QKDSK305.sinks.UserActionSink.hdfs.rollInterval = 120
QKDSK305.sinks.UserActionSink.hdfs.rollSize = 131072
QKDSK305.sinks.UserActionSink.serializer = com.dynatrace.diagnostics.btexport.flume.BtPageActionSerializerBuilder

QKDSK305.sinks.VisitSink.type = hdfs
QKDSK305.sinks.VisitSink.hdfs.path = hdfs://QKDSK303:9000/user/bts/visit
QKDSK305.sinks.VisitSink.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
QKDSK305.sinks.VisitSink.hdfs.filePrefix = export
QKDSK305.sinks.VisitSink.hdfs.fileSuffix = .txt
QKDSK305.sinks.VisitSink.hdfs.rollInterval = 120
QKDSK305.sinks.VisitSink.hdfs.rollSize = 131072
QKDSK305.sinks.VisitSink.serializer = com.dynatrace.diagnostics.btexport.flume.BtVisitSerializerBuilder
QKDSK305.sinks.VisitSink.serializer.charset = ISO-8859-2
QKDSK305.sinks.NullSink.type = null
QKDSK305.channels.NullChannel.type = memory

# Use a channel which buffers events in memory
QKDSK305.channels.PurePathChannel.type = memory
QKDSK305.channels.PurePathChannel.capacity = 1000
QKDSK305.channels.PurePathChannel.transactionCapactiy = 100

QKDSK305.channels.UserActionChannel.type = memory
QKDSK305.channels.UserActionChannel.capacity = 1000
QKDSK305.channels.UserActionChannel.transactionCapactiy = 100

QKDSK305.channels.VisitChannel.type = memory
QKDSK305.channels.VisitChannel.capacity = 1000
QKDSK305.channels.VisitChannel.transactionCapactiy = 100

# Bind the source and sink to the channel
QKDSK305.sources.HTTPSource.channels = PurePathChannel UserActionChannel VisitChannel NullChannel
QKDSK305.sinks.PurePathSink.channel = PurePathChannel
QKDSK305.sinks.UserActionSink.channel = UserActionChannel
QKDSK305.sinks.VisitSink.channel = VisitChannel
QKDSK305.sinks.NullSink.channel = NullChannel

QKDSK305.sources.HTTPSource.selector.type = multiplexing
QKDSK305.sources.HTTPSource.selector.header = btType
QKDSK305.sources.HTTPSource.selector.mapping.PUREPATH = PurePathChannel
QKDSK305.sources.HTTPSource.selector.mapping.PAGE_ACTION = UserActionChannel
QKDSK305.sources.HTTPSource.selector.mapping.VISIT = VisitChannel
QKDSK305.sources.HTTPSource.selector.default = NullChannel
```

---

Kindly help.

Thanks,
Pranil

Answer (score 0):

It seems that one of our other users ran into a similiar issue. They fixed the problem by recompiling Flume with protobuf 2.5.
Instead of copying what they posted on our dynatrace community forum feel free to check out their posting here: https://community.compuwareapm.com/community/display/DL/Big+Data+Business+Transaction+Bridge?focusedCommentId=192087283#comment-192087283

Andi